# R - Unicode symbol "dot above" as thousands separator

Tags: r, unicode, separator

I work with R and I would like to use the Unicode symbol "dot above" as thousands separator for data contained in a dataframe (not for plotting), for example: 1˙000˙000 instead of 1,000,000

The character code of "dot above" is 02D9 (taken from Microsoft Word); when I type the command:

```
"\u02D9"
```

the result is the symbol "dot above":

```
"˙"
```

I changed the option "scipen":

`options(scipen = 10)`

and then I tried three different solutions:

1.

```
format(1000000, big.mark = "\u02D9")
```

2.

```
format(1000000, big.mark = intToUtf8("0x02D9"))
```

3.

```
library(Unicode)
format(1000000, big.mark = intToUtf8(as.u_char("02D9")))
```

but the result is always:

```
"1™Ë000™Ë000"
```

Maybe it's about the encoding system (I live in Italy and I use Microsoft Windows 7 on my computer) or maybe the solution is simpler than the ones I tried but I don't know how to deal with it.

Does anybody know how to do it?

Thanks in advance for any suggestion.

Comment: The problem is `gsub`. Example for further investigation: `gsub("1", "\U02D9", 123, fixed=TRUE)`

Answer (score 1):

As @Roland mentions `gsub` and `sub` used by `prettyNum` mangle the encoding. Unfortunately you cannot simply reset it afterwards to recover your data since the mangling converts it to two characters, and `prettyNum` reverses their order:

```
`Encoding<-`(format(1000, big.mark = "\u02D9"),"UTF-8")
[1] "1\u0099\xcb000"
```

The best way to work around is to `format` with a safe character and swap and change encoding afterwards:

```
`Encoding<-`(gsub(",","\u02d9",format(1e6,big.mark=",")),"UTF-8")
[1] "1˙000˙000"
```

Comment: Do you know how to convert a character vector `"1˙000˙000" "2˙000˙000" "3˙000˙000" "4˙000˙000"` into a dataframe keeping the Unicode symbol "dot above" as thousands separator? (See next post)